# Exception during setting up SonarLint in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I am using IntelliJ (v2018.1.2) and trying to get the SonarLint (3.3.0.2482) plugin to work. When I select `Configure SonarLint` on the SonarLint panel and click `Configure Servers...` after checking `Enable binding to remote SonarQube server` it does nothing and gives me the following error.

The SonarLint installation guide says that all you need is Java 8, which I have (1.8.0) and to install it from the Plugins directory -> browse repositories which I did. I've tried updating IntelliJ and SonarLint and removing any plugins that aren't automatically included in IntelliJ and to see if they were interacting but unsure where to go from here. Anyone else encounter this? Thanks for reading.

[image: IntelliJ Exception]

Full exception text is here:

```
com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaPlugin.getExtensions(JavaPlugin.java:50)
    at org.sonar.api.SonarPlugin.define(SonarPlugin.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.global.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:55)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.global.GlobalExtensionContainer.doBeforeStart(GlobalExtensionContainer.java:37)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageContainer.doAfterStart(StorageContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.start(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:120)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.<init>(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:79)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.core.SonarLintEngineFactory.createEngine(SonarLintEngineFactory.java:63)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.core.SonarLintEngineManager.getConnectedEngine(SonarLintEngineManager.java:110)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.global.SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.switchTo(SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.java:283)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.global.SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.onServerSelect(SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.java:272)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.global.SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.lambda$create$0(SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.java:121)
    at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1796)
    at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1810)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:459)
    at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedIndex(JList.java:2210)
    at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedValue(JList.java:2360)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.global.SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.load(SonarQubeServerMgmtPanel.java:262)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.global.SonarLintGlobalConfigurable.reset(SonarLintGlobalConfigurable.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.reset(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.lambda$createConfigurableComponent$0(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:927)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.createConfigurableComponent(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:69)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.create(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:70)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.createValue(CardLayoutPanel.java:88)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:116)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.<init>(ConfigurableEditor.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.<init>(SettingsDialog.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialogFactory.create(SettingsDialogFactory.java:37)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:217)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:212)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.project.SonarLintProjectBindPanel.actionConfigureServers(SonarLintProjectBindPanel.java:288)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.project.SonarLintProjectBindPanel.access$100(SonarLintProjectBindPanel.java:67)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.config.project.SonarLintProjectBindPanel$1.actionPerformed(SonarLintProjectBindPanel.java:223)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:779)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:716)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:395)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:694)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:426)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1688)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1637)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.lambda$show$0(SettingsDialog.java:69)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.show(SettingsDialog.java:69)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1652)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:241)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:202)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:175)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.actions.SonarConfigureProject.actionPerformed(SonarConfigureProject.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:357)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:779)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:716)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:395)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 139 more
```

Comment: File a bug at https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI or contact sonarlint@googlegroups.com for help.

Comment: Note: also posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/sonarlint/HDcUw8b0EjU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the SonarLint google group, it was suggested that SonarLint was pulling in an older version of a plugin and to check the contents of the plugin lib. The contents for this version were:

```
commons-lang-2.6.jar 
jsr305-2.0.2.jar 
sonarlint-client-api-3.3.0.1492.jar 
sonarlint-core-3.3.0.1492.jar 
sonarlint-intellij-3.3.0.2482.jar
```

Which was verified as correct. Also, it was suggested to clear out all local storage in .../config/plugins/SonarLint to remove the local data cache.

I also removed any previous version of local caches from IntelliJ which apparently do not get cleaned up after each release.

Doing the above resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you AHalbert. I had the exact same issue with the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList error as well as Intellij freezing because of it! Per your comment, I uninstalled SonarLint, deleted C:\Users\username\\.Intellij2018.1/config/SonarLint completely, reinstalled SonarLint and it worked! Also, have to say that I hadn't configured Java SDK (I thought that happened by default). So both together were needed and the error went away and I am able to configure SonarLint now.

Answer (score 1):

For Sonar Lint plugin(v4.0.2.3009) I had a similar issue, the configure servers button was not opening. If you had a previous configuration of Sonar Qube done in Sonar Lint in your IDE(IntelliJ2019.3), there is the off-chance that you might get a java error from the plugin when trying to configure a new server or after selecting the configured one that does not respond anymore, leaving you without any possibility of configuring a different server, because the window for configuring server no longer opens. Uninstalling the plugin will not remove the configured servers. So, in order to get the plugin working again you need to do the following:

- uninstall the plugin and close the IDE
- remove the "sonarlint" folder from the following path "~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/"
- also remove ~Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/options/sonarlint.xml
- not sure if required but I also removed the plugin cache, which is in    "~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.1/plugins/"
- install the plugin back and configure the new server